# pg-promise: Transactions: Handling missing properties

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.4, pg-promise

This is the query I pass into a batch transaction:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(${id}, ${name}, ${crtd});
```

The input array may or may not contain one of the keys, say `${crtd}`.
This throws `Error: property 'crtd' does not exist` and the entire batch fails.

I still want this row to be inserted, containing only `{id}` and `{name}`. The `${crtd}` is a nullable column too.

In the below, 'l' is the input json missing the key ${crtd}.

```
                           db.tx(t=>t.batch(valuesArray.map(l=>t.none(query, l))))                         So, the only way to do this is additional logic that checks for missing keys and adds them?
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Why not just assign a default value to the formatting object before running the query?

Comment: Currently I have no formatting logic in place and pulling the input JSON array from a WebService. Did not want to add additional logic, if I could get the transaction to ignore missing Keys in each input json object. Missing values is working allright, but missing keys is the problem, because ${crtd} refers to a key in the input json. So, the only way to do this is additional logic that checks for missing keys and adds them?

Comment: Edited the original question to include the Tx described by you in another thread.

Comment: If you talking about inserting records from JSON, you should look at [helpers.insert](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.insert), you can set default/init values via `ColumnSet` ;)

Comment: Much thanks for ur quick response @vitaly-t! I will check it.